# how to detect non human touch on screen

Tags: android, touch

I am creating an weight measuring app for android for that
I want to detect a `non human touch` on `android screen` so that by measuring its pressure i will be able to detect the weight of the object placed on screen but the problem is `capicitive screen` of android are detecting only `human touch` .

please help

Comment: hehehe with non human i want to say any object as coin,paper weight etc

Comment: sounds awesome.. i am hitting the favorite icon..

Answer (score 1):

It's all about whether the material used is conductive (not only human touch is copnductive). That's just how capacitive screens works. It isn't possible to detect a touch with e.g. a rock, because that isn't conductive.

A coin on the other hand may just work. Because most coins (at least where I am from) contain conductive material.

Comment: thanks for your reply means only conductive objects will work and other as a lip balm not ????

Comment: @vipw "Jason Kottke highlights a trend in South Korea in which iPhone users are using snack sausages as meat styli" Strange people those iPhone owners ;) Fun link though thanks

Comment: How about the touch surface area ? May be human touches come under a specified radius ! ?

Comment: PeeHaa is there any way by which non conductive touch can be measured

Comment: No. Not that I know of for capacitive screens. Perhaps some models (now or in the future) will have other ways of capturing touches. E.g. "cameras" (think MS pixelsense like technique). But I don't know of any phone which does that.

Comment: A floating coin will not work. To detect a touch, the object has to be conductive AND it has to be coupled to ground. A coin is too small to couple to ground through the air.